# Handle logins in the multidatabase SSDT solution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have solution that has multiple databases in it. I would like to add logins/users/permissions to the project. I have the DB project that references DB projects that are created for the databases that are on the same server but in different databases.

When I've added login and the user to the first project everything worked fine. After that I've added user to the 2nd database project (as the server is the same and I do not need to create login again). Then the build complains that there is o login for the user. If I add login to the 2nd project then it complains that the object exists already ...

I am not sure what is the right solution for my problem, but I would like to have something like:

1. Project "DbA" has both login and user in the project;
2. Project "DbB" has user in the project that uses login from the project "DbA".

Any other suggestions are welcome.

EDITED:
As a workaround I've created new project where I've added this login and the added this project as a reference to all needed DBs, but I do not really like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I took the login/user info out of the solutions, mostly because we used different ones depending on the environments. We then added/tweaked them with post-deploy scripts. This is based off of Jamie Thomson's work, but may be helpful for you: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

Alternatively, you could just add the login information to each project, but that could also get troublesome to maintain after a while. SSDT should be smart enough to not mess with the login if it already exists.

Comment: Yes, usually I am using approach you are talking about. However in that case I tried to put into the solution. As I marked in the question that I've found workaround and it works, however it is not very easy to maintain.